# eliminating duplicate value in sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a Sql Statement which its result is something like following

```
  TagNo1         TagNo2
 ---------------------------
   63516         63546
   63546         63516
```

How can set it that I need just one record . For example

```
    TagNo1         TagNo2
 ---------------------------
     63516         63546
```

or the other, no difference. because it is the same for me?

Thank you

Comment: just add `TagNo1  >  TagNo2` condition into the SQL

Answer (score 4):

Return a row if TagNo1 is less or equal to TagNo2. Or if the switched values don't exist.

```
select distinct TagNo1, TagNo2
from tablename t1
where TagNo1 <= TagNo2
   or not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t1.TagNo1 = t2.TagNo2
                    and t1.TagNo2 = t2.TagNo1)
```

Do `select distinct` to avoid duplicates if TagNo1 = TagNo2.

Or use `case` expressions:

```
select distinct case when TagNo1 <= TagNo2 then TagNo1 else TagNo2 end,
                case when TagNo1 >= TagNo2 then TagNo1 else TagNo2 end
from tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t table (col1 int, col2 int);
insert into @t values (63516, 63546), (63546, 63516);

select col1, col2 
from @t 
where col1 <= col2 
union 
select col2, col1 
from @t 
where col2 < col1
```